# Show/hide input fields based on other input selections

Tags: pine-script

I was wondering if Pine Script has the possibility to conditionally show or hide input fields based on other input field selection values.

I've tried putting an `input B` inside of an `if` statement based on another `input A`, but `input B` is always displayed.
So I'm guessing this is not possible.

If so, are there plans to make that available?
Or is there a place where we can make suggestions (and vote) for desired Pine Script functionalities?

Comment: I think it is indeed impossible to hide inputs, you can suggest your ideas here https://getsatisfaction.com/tradingview?view=recent

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done for the moment. Something like this is possible though:

```
//@version=4
study("")
STEP    = 0.5
MINVAL  = 0.0
f_01(_bool) => _bool ? 1 : 0
i_atoms                 = input(true,   "═════════ Include Atom Weights ════════")
i_atom01                = f_01(i_atoms) * input(1.0, minval = MINVAL, step = STEP, title = "Up Bar")
plot(i_atom01)
```

No it's not currently planned to add this feature.

> I suggest you PM @LucF on TV.

Comment: At least disabling an entire group with a checkbox would be helpful as it would reduce clutter in the status line for the indicator and make it clearer to user which values are unused.

Comment: Agree. The original design we proposed to the charting team was to make groups expandable/collapsible, but it wasn't included in the MVP. Perhaps we'll get there in the future )

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF are still some ideas to implement this. Showing/hiding options based on checkbox would be a game changer for more complex templates/indicators/strategies

Comment: We're hoping for a Phase II of the feature that will increase the visibility of the group header and make the groups collapsible, but it is not yet in the short-term pipeline.